# How do I call the JFrame (the class itself) inside a windowslistener method?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to reference the JFrame (which is the class itself) inside a WindowsListener method. Is there any way to do this?

```
    diag_ap.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            this.setEnabled(true); //does not work
        }
    });
```

I expect to call the class frame and disable it so that the only thing that can be pressed is the JDialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `this` keyword inside `new WindowAdapter().windowClosing(event)` method refers to the WindowAdapter object that you created.

To refer the object of the JFrame inside WindowAdapter, you should use `MyJFrame.this`. So, the code should be,

```
diag_ap.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            MyJFrame.this.setEnabled(true); // replace MyJFrame with name of your JFrame
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is, the JFrame I'm referring to is the class itself. Can I still use that method?